# Which Documentation should i use for visual studio extension development?

Tags: visual-studio, documentation, visual-studio-extensions

I want develop a Visual Studio Extension, which would deploy my project changes on the server via sftp.

I searched for Microsoft documentation in the internet and found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/visual-studio-sdk?view=vs-2019).

But this documentation don't helps me. It don't shows me Methods like how to access the FileSystem to detect changes in files or how to usw sftp to upload them etc.

Comment: What do you mean `deploy project changes`? Something works like git version control?

Comment: There is an Project, that is version controlled via git, but you must changes the files manual on the server and reload the server. Don't ask me why it was made so idk. So i dont want make the changes manually. I want vs make it automatically.

Comment: Hi Q-bert, as far as I know, there's not such kind of [vsix documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/visual-studio-sdk?view=vs-2019)  about using sftp in extension to deploy project changes to server. You can send your feedback about the documents at the bottom of the page to share your requirement.